# Ruby: correctly load a file in parent directory, which file depends on another file

Tags: ruby, load

I know it is a twisted headline... I am a rookie programming in ruby and here is my problem:

There are two files containing different functions, and one of them is calling the other

File a.rb:
`def f1(v1)......`

File b.rb:
`load "a.rb"

def f2(v2)......`

Both of the files above are in the parent directory. Now if I call `b.rb` in the current directory using either `load` or `require`, I will have the same error:

`` LoadError: cannot load such file -- a.rb

    from /Users/username/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:45:in require'
    from /Users/username/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:45:inrequire'
    from /Users/username/b.rb:1:in `' ``

For this situation, I came up with two solutions:
1) put `f2` into file `a.rb`.
2) Or delete the line `load "a.rb"` in the file `b.rb`, and `load` both files in my implementation.

But I think either way would undermine the logic relation/distinction between these two files. These two files face different kinds of problems, while the function `f2` cannot perform anything without `f1`.

My question is: is there any way to separate the two functions in two files meanwhile just loading once (without knowing any dependency between the functions)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In file b.rb:

```
require_relative "./a.rb"
def f2(v2)......
```

See http://extensions.rubyforge.org/rdoc/classes/Kernel.html